Young boy in the holocaust after being separated from his family, loves planes
I watched the movie about 5-10 years ago. It isn't the striped pajama one. A boy is raised in a rich family (and he really likes planes I think?) Soldiers begin invading wherever he is, and he begins running in a crowed of people with his family. He is then separated from his family after dropping his toy plane and trying to pick it up. He is then put into a concentration camp. I'm blurry on what happens after that, I believe he has a piece of soap in the camp at one point and is almost killed for it, but someone else takes it and is killed instead. Another thing I vaguely remember is he goes to work in a factory or something while he is in the camp? Does anyone know what this movie is called?

Empire of the Sun (1987) with Christian Bale, John Malkovich and Miranda Richardson.

Based on J. G. Ballard's autobiographical novel, tells the story of a boy, James Graham, whose privileged life is upturned by the Japanese invasion of Shanghai, December 8, 1941. Separated from his parents, he is eventually captured, and taken to Soo Chow confinement camp, next to a captured Chinese airfield. Amidst the sickness and food shortages in the camp, Jim attempts to reconstruct his former life, all the while bringing spirit and dignity to those around him. 

Both of the scenes you mentioned (the one with the toy plane and the one with the soap) are there.




You just beat me to this answer! :) GREAT movie.

One of Christian Bale's first movies when he was just a kid.
